# Method comparing the reverse order of integers

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to compare the reverse order of the two integers, but for some reason it is giving me `true`. I am trying to figure out where is my mistake but can't seem to find it.

Here is my code:

```
    int a=4234;
    int b=4326;

    System.out.print(reverseSame(a,b));
}

public static boolean reverseSame(int a, int b) {
    int n1=0;
    int n2=0;
    int temp1=a;
    int temp2=b;

    while(temp1>0) {
        temp1/=10;
        n1++;
    }

    while(temp2>0) {
        temp2/=10;
        n2++;
    }

    if (n1!=n2)
        return false;
    else {
        boolean isEqual=true;

        int []arrA = new int[n1];
        int []arrB = new int[n1];

        for (int i=n1-1; i>=0; i--) {
            arrA[i]=temp1%10;
            arrB[i]=temp2%10;

            temp1/=10;
            temp2/=10;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<n1/2;i++) {
            if (arrA[i]!=arrB[n1-i-1]) {
                isEqual=false;
            }
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: `while(temp2>0) {
        temp2/=10;
        n2++;

    }` Can you tell me what do you mean here by temp2 /= 10; ?

Comment: I think it counts the amount of digits. `temp2>0` asserts that there is a number left, while `temp2=temp2/10` chunks away by a radix of 1.

Comment: Simply convert both of them from integers to string , reverse one of two of them and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your code reaches this point:

```
        arrA[i]=temp1%10;
        arrB[i]=temp2%10;
```

Both `temp1` and `temp2` are already at zero (after exiting `while` loop). You need to set them both to `a` and `b` again after the while loop ends.